# how use interval RxJava in Recyclerview in android

Tags: android, rx-java2, intervals

I have a list of one chat object (ArrayList)that I want to show them with delay between items in recyclerview
How to do this operation?
Is there a code like this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `LayoutAnimator` on `RecyclerView`

```
fun RecyclerView.animateDropDown() {
    layoutAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(context, R.anim.layout_animation_fall_down)
    scheduleLayoutAnimation()
}
```

Or if you want to use `Rx` do:

```
Observable.interval(0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe {
                    adapter.addItem(item)
                }
```

JAVA

```
        int index = 0;
        Observable.interval(0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<Long>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Long value) {
                      adapter.addItem(index);
                      index++;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                    }
                });
```

Also do not forget to notify adapter each time when item is inserted with `adapter.notifyItemInserted(position)`

Comment: Do you have a complete sample Java code for RxJava?

Comment: Updated answer with JAVA solution

Comment: how add all items Arraylist in fragment declare into adapter with Observable.interval...? in for loop?

Comment: Use index, add index++ on every item add. See updated answer

Comment: do you have sample project like it?

Comment: do you have link that set recyclerview with interval?

Comment: Can't wait for this to leak infinitely.

Comment: yes, you have to dispose it after and finish up the code, this is just an example how to do rx interval and recyclerview......